# Grouping multiple dplyr::filter() expressions R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Is there a more efficient way of coding multiple exclusion filters in R using `dplyr`? My problem is similar to this [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890522/group-data-and-filter-groups-by-two-columns-dplyr).

Simplified example of my data:

```
data<-data.frame(age=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4),wt=c(32,12,5,32,80,32,1,0,4,8,1,1,2,50))
```

I go on to filter out extreme values based on numerous different conditions depending on the `age` variable and the `mean` and `sd` of the `wt` variable.

My current solution looks like this:

```
data_clean<-data%>%filter(
    !(age==1 & wt<6),
    !(age==1 & wt>20),
    !(age==2 & wt >= (mean((data%>%filter(age==2))$wt) +sd((data%>%filter(age==2))$wt))), 
    !(age==2 & wt <= (mean((data%>%filter(age==2))$wt)-sd((data%>%filter(age==2))$wt))),
    !(age==3 & wt >= (mean((data%>%filter(age==3))$wt) +sd((data%>%filter(age==3))$wt))), 
    !(age==3 & wt <= (mean((data%>%filter(age==3))$wt)-sd((data%>%filter(age==3))$wt))),
    !(age==4 & wt >= (mean((data%>%filter(age==4))$wt) +2*sd((data%>%filter(age==4))$wt))), 
    !(age==4 & wt <= (mean((data%>%filter(age==4))$wt)-2*sd((data%>%filter(age==4))$wt)))
        )
```

I have also tried:

```
filter(!wt %in% wt[age==2 & wt >= (mean(wt) +sd(wt))], 
       !wt %in% wt[age==2 & wt <= (mean(wt) -sd(wt))]), etc...
```

**EDIT:** Note that the filter arguments are not the same for all ages. I am applying the same filter to `age==2` and `age==3` and then a different filter to `age==4`. In all cases, the `mean()` and `sd()` are relative to the `age`. So, at `age==2`, I am filtering based on the `mean()` wt at `age==2` and the `sd()` at `age==2`.

BUT, these are really cumbersome solutions and is not going to be feasible for me given I actually have 8 different exclusion criteria across multiple ages (1-50).

How can I group multiple arguments together? For example, the filtering is the same for `age==2` and `age==3`. Instead of having 4 lines, is there a way to only have 2 lines?

In this example, the final dataset should look like this:

```
     age  wt
      1  12
      2  32
      2  32
      3   1
      3   0
      4   4
      4   8
      4   1
      4   1
      4   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify things by standardizing the wt variable by age:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(age) %>%
  mutate(x = abs(scale(wt)[,1])) %>%
  filter(age %in% 2:3 & x <= 1 | age == 4 & x <= 2 | age == 1 & wt > 6 & age == 1 & wt < 20) %>%
  select(-x) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 2
     age    wt
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    12
 2     2    32
 3     2    32
 4     3     1
 5     3     0
 6     4     4
 7     4     8
 8     4     1
 9     4     1
10     4     2
```

Comment: If I wanted to specify a range of ages for the `age == 4 & x <= 2` argument, would this `age %in% c(2:4) & x <= 2` be appropriate? I didn't ask about this in the original question, but I think your solution is going to be very adaptable to my problem

Comment: Yes, that is appropriate in selecting multiple ages.

Comment: I updated the answer to what I think you want based on the expected output.  Let me know if it's not correct.